# Needing help writing Dijkstra's Algorithm

Tags: java, dijkstra, shortest-path

I am trying write Dijkstras Algorithm into the code I have written below. But I am unsure how to start doing this. I did review it a bit from online sources, but I am still unsure how to make it work really. I prefer to place it into the evaluate paths method. Then have the menu option call this method and it perform the sorting algorithm.

FYI. I am sorting the shortest path from City A to City B by miles and price.

Below is the code I have.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class CityCalcultor { 
   static LinkedList<String> cities = new LinkedList<String>();
   static LinkedList<Integer> distance = new LinkedList<Integer>();
   static LinkedList<Integer> price = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException 
    {
     Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
     String text;
     int option = 0;   
      while (true)
      {   
       System.out.println("\nWhat would you like to do:\n" +
       "1. Add a city to the system\n" +
      "2. Add a path to the system\n" +
      "3. Evalute paths\n" +
       "4. Exit\n" + "Your option: ");
       text = input.nextLine();
       option = Integer.parseInt(text);

        switch (option)
        {
         case 1: EnterCity(); break;
         case 2: EnterPath(); break;
         case 3: EvalutePaths(); break;
         case 4: return;
         default: System.out.println("ERROR INVALID INPUT");
        }
       }
      }
public static void EnterCity(){
   String c = "";
   LinkedList<String> cities = new LinkedList<String>(Arrays.asList(c));
   Scanner City = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println("Please enter the city name ");
   c = City.nextLine();
   cities.add(c);
   System.out.println("City " + c + " has been added ");

}
public static void EnterPath(){
   Scanner Path = new Scanner(System.in);
   int d = 0; int p = 0;
   System.out.println("Enter the starting city ");
   System.out.println();
   System.out.println(Path.nextLine());
   System.out.println("Enter the ending city ");
   System.out.println(Path.nextLine());
   System.out.println("Enter the distance between the two cities ");
   d= Path.nextInt();
   distance.add(d);
   System.out.println("Enter the price between the two cities ");
   p = Path.nextInt();

   price.add(p);
   System.out.println("The route was sucessfully added ");


}
private static void EvalutePaths(){


}
}
```

Output should look like::

Shortest Route from Seattle to San Francisco is 1290 miles.

Comment: What specifically do you want help with?  What parts of the algorithm are you having the most trouble understanding?

Comment: I see a program, but no Djikstra's :( For what it's worth, Wikipedia as decent articles on both Djikstra's and A*. There are two *separate* parts: 1) The data (what the program is gathering), although might as well just use an array of static data for testing and 2) The shortest path algorithm. *Keep* them separate. (And, "Not a real question" ;-)

Comment: I am having a hard time trying to figure out how to pass the data from the array into the algorithm. I am totally confused with algorithm from beginning to end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is some **pseudo** code for Dijkstra's algorithm, perhaps it will help..

this will set the shortest distance to each city from the starting city..

```
for each city
{
    settled = false
    distance = infinity
}

startingCity.distance = 0

currentCity = startingCity

while not all cities are settled
{
    for each city adjacent to the current city
    {
        newDist = distance from adjacentCity to currentCity

        if newDist < adjacentCity.distance
        {
            adjacentCity.distance = newDist
        }  
    }

    currentCity.settled = true

    currentCity = city closest to currentCity
}
```

Comment: I've edited it since you accepted the answer as it was incorrect, 'currentCity.settled = true' must be outside the for loop.

Comment: I hate to ask this but is there any way you can show me the algorithm without the pseudocode?

Answer (score 1):

If I can make a modest suggestion that might make coding this easier:
Try creating a City and Link class and then create a node graph instead of just using Lists.

Dijkstra's Algorithm is a graph traversal algorithm, and if you try this just using an array, you're going to run into some semantic problems separating what values represent what paths.  (Looking at the path input method, it looks like you already are)

Perhaps you want to create some classes like:

```
public class City {
  String name;
  List<Road> connectingRoads;

}

public class Road {
  List<City> connectingCities;
  Float distance;
  Float price;

  // Technically this COULD be for more than two cities... mainly I wrote it this way simply to make coding and use easier.
  Road(Float distance, Float price, City... connectingCities) {
    this.distance = distance;
    this.price = price;
    connectingCities = new ArrayList(connectingCities);
    for (City city : connectingCities) {
       city.connectingRoads.add(this);
    }
  }
}
```

This will give you an actual graph structure to traverse, and makes the semantic input problem much less problematic, as you can look up cities from the array, and then add a road based on the input values given.  Graph traversal is then done by looking at the connectingRoads list on each City record.

You also want one more class to keep track of your paths and costs found during graph traversal, as this is part of the Dijkstra's algorithm.  I found keeping such data even after finding the shortest path to be very helpful in the case of a maze running program I wrote in college. We used it to display the fastest path from the current point in the maze, without any additional calculation required after the algorithm had run once. Although to be fair, we ran the algorithm backwards from the goal to all points in the maze - to determine the furthest point - so we could start the player there ><

Comment: I am sorry I dont understand this at all :S

Comment: Conceptually, Dijkstra's algorithm is a graph, which consists of nodes and connections. See the WikiPedia image at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm.  In your case, you are using Cities and Roads, which have a distance and price/toll.  Conceptually, you need a good way to represent which nodes (cities) connect where, and at what distance/price, hence why I'm recommending you abandon your current multiple List approach, in favor of listing Nodes (cities) and the Connections (roads) between them instead.  It makes organizing the information more natural and less error-prone.